# Starting word match

Tags: python-3.x

i wrote a sorting script, but the artist is also found in the middle of the word

the structure looks like this :

```
/home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_sorted/Farid_Bang_Feat._Kollegah_und_Fler_-_PUBLIC_ENEMIES

/home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_Archiv/F/Fler/
/home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_Archiv/F/Farid/
```

but now will Farid_Bang_Feat.*Kollegah_und_Fler*-_PUBLIC_ENEM moved to the wrong directory.
i want it in /home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_Archiv/F/Farid/ and not in /home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_Archiv/F/Fler/

the artist must be fixed on the start of the word in the name. because Fler also occurs in the string

I tried ^ but it doesn't work

```
if re.search(^artist, name):
```

.

```
import os
import re
import shutil  

main_path = '/home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_Archiv'
sort_path = '/home/jail/user/archiv/MP3/MP3_sorted'


def main():
    dirlist = [item for item in os.listdir(main_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(main_path, item))]
    for dir in dirlist:
        for dir2 in dir:
            dir2 = main_path + '/' + dir2
            dirlist2 = [item for item in os.listdir(dir2) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(dir2, item))]
            for artist in dirlist2:
                print('artist', artist)
                dirlist3 = [item for item in os.listdir(sort_path) if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(sort_path, item))]
                for name in dirlist3:
                    chara = artist[:1]
                    source = sort_path + '/' + name
                    destination = main_path + '/' + chara + '/' + artist + '/'
                    if re.search(artist, name):
                        shutil.move(source, destination)
                        print('name moved to', destination + name)


main()
print('done')
```

Comment: `if re.search('^' + artist, name):`???

Comment: nice idea, thanks ,working for me

Answer (score 0):

You wrote

> ```
> if re.search(artist, name):
> ```

Johnny Mopp explains that this implements your desired search criterion:

```
if re.search('^' + artist, name):
```